# TargetPlatform.windows is not yet supported by the flutter_inappwebview plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, target-platform, flutter-inappwebview

[Flutter code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zdUB.png)

[Command info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLaJR.png)

[Remaining command info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T91ZW.png)

I searched about this problem then I found a solution to run command "flutter config --enable-windows-desktop" and "flutter config --enable-android" then I restart my computer but still facing the same problem.
Also I have kept minSDKversion to 19.
This code is not running in any platform.

Comment: use [webview_windows: ^0.2.2](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_windows) it's supported on windows

Comment: @Ruchit Hi, I don't see any implementation of `webview_windows` on  `pub.dev`, could you please help me to implement it?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_windows/example here you can get the example code for webview_windows package.

Answer (score 3):

Its simply because [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package doesn't have support for Windows platform. Always check platforms supported before using packages.

follow [this](https://pub.dev/packages?q=platform%3Awindows+webview) link to view list of webview packages filtered by platform